# PL/SQL Record populate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a record as following and I want to populate this with a for loop.

```
declare 
  type ch_type is table of record(id number, name varchar2(50));
  type ch_type_tab is table of ch_type;
  rec_typr ch_type_tab;
begin
  for i in (select * from emp) loop
    rec_typr.id := i.emp_id;
    rec_typr.name := i.first_name;
  end loop;
  for i in rec_typr.first..rec_typr.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_typr(i).id);
  end loop;
end;
```

but I get the error:

```
PLS:0302 component first must be declared.
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you want to write `rec_typr.id := i.emp_id;` then `rec_typr` should have the type `record(id number, name varchar2(50))`, but it currently has type `ch_type_tab`. What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 1):

Two things are problematic in your code.

1) `type ch_type is table of record` is syntactically incorrect. You must first declare a record and then define its collection type.

2) Using implicit cursor loop  is not an efficient method to load a collection and definitely can't be done the way you're trying to do. Use much simpler `BULK COLLECT` method instead.

```
declare 
  type ch_type is  record(id number, name varchar2(50));
  type ch_type_tab is table of ch_type;
  rec_typr ch_type_tab;
begin
   select emp_id,first_name  bulk collect into 
       rec_typr from emp;

  for i in rec_typr.first..rec_typr.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_typr(i).id);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**EDIT**

> I need to populate the record through a loop not through bulk collect.
>   Is it any way?

Yes, there is. But, it is *less efficient* than the method described above.

```
declare 
  type ch_type is  record(id number, name varchar2(50));
  type ch_type_tab is table of ch_type;
  rec_typr ch_type_tab := ch_type_tab();
  i INTEGER := 1;
begin
rec_typr.extend;
for rec in 
(
   select emp_id,first_name  bulk collect into 
       rec_typr from emp
       ) 
   loop 
       rec_typr(i).id   := rec.emp_id;
       rec_typr(i).name := rec.first_name;
       rec_typr.extend;
       i := i + 1;
   end loop;

  for i in rec_typr.first..rec_typr.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_typr(i).id);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: I need to populate the record through a loop not through bulk collect. Is it any way?

Comment: A lot of thanks Kaushik. It is a less efficient, but I need it like this. Thank you